# Как скрыть определенное значение из вывода значений массива

Tags: php

Есть массив, в нем содержится множество элементов, массив вывожу на странице.

В массиве есть записи которые выводить не нужно. Хочу сделать условие чтобы эти записи просто не выводило, но в массиве они оставались.

Записи которые не нужно выводить выглядят так: `Отобразить еще 15 элементов`

где 15 - всегда разное значение. хотелось бы что-то вроде такого:

```
foreach ($allLinkPageArticle as $keyPA => $valuePA) {
    if (!если это не -Отобразить еще n элементов-)
      echo $valuePA;
      echo "<hr>";
    }
}
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: `strpos` или регулярные выражения.

Comment: @u_mulder благодарю, `strpos` помогла.

Comment: Используйте array_filter

Answer (score -1):

Вот так сделал:

```
foreach ($allLinkPageArticle as $keyPA => $valuePA) {
  if (strpos($valuePA, 'Отобразить') === false)
    echo $valuePA;
    echo "<hr>";
  }
}
```

спасибо пользователю *u_mulder* за наводку.